# Moderator Election - Incorrect link in sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election

There is a sidebar next to [the moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) with some information about the process:

[image: sidebar next to the moderator election]

Snippet from the text:

> We will calculate the winners using OpaVote with the Meek STV method [...]

The "Meek STV method" part points to the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method#Meek.27s_method

**This link has an incorrect target**, and because of that, it goes to the top of the "Counting single transferable votes" article instead of jumping to the method the text is about. I'd suggest changing it to one of the following links (the first link redirects to the second):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek

Comment: In your image, where am I supposed to be looking again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  I'm using the redirecting link per Shog's suggestion in case things get moved again.

Interestingly, Wikipedia's canonical page redirects don't act like you might expect.  HTTP doesn't get fragments so only `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meek%27s_method` got sent to the server.  I would expect Wikipedia to return a redirect response to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes#Meek` since that is the new home of the content.

Instead, Wikipedia serves the content of `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_single_transferable_votes` from the initial request then updates the URL in place to the canonical URL and only navigates to `#Meek` if there wasn't already a fragment provided.  I guess this is ideal for cases where you're linking to a fragment in an article that was renamed or an article that was moved into a fragment, but fails in our case where we were linking to a fragment that became a fragment with a different name.